# I am getting type error for 3 arguments but i have passed exactly 2 arguments

Tags: oop, methods, arguments, python-3.8

I have written the following code in Python and I am facing the following issue regarding the arguments of the class method.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add an initial argument `self` to the definition of the method `print_details`.  I.e. `def print_details(name,age):` should be `def print_details(self,name,age):`

You don't explicitly pass `self` when calling methods, python does that for you.  That's why it looks like you've passed 2 but the interpreter says you passed 3.